# Can somebody explain the various syntaxes for Blazor component tags

Tags: blazor

In my .razor files I have these tags (just an example). They work but I cannot explain to myself the reasons behind the various syntaxes

```
<HxButton Text=@StartButtonText OnClick="StartClick" Color="ThemeColor.Primary"/>
        
<Listener @ref=_listener/>
    
<button  @onclick=Show>Modal</button>
```

Specifically

- Why do some tags have an @ at the start of the name (like ref and onclick) and others not.
- Why is ThemeColor.Primary in quotes but not StartButtonText
- Why does StartButtonText have an @ sign
- Why does the @onclick for the button have plain text (not @Show or "Show")

I hate randomly cycling through syntaxes each time to find one that works.

Note, HxButton is from the HAVIT component library, Listener is my component built on top of HAVIT HxModal

Comment: Razor files get compiled into C# classes.  The semantics issues you've brought up are about how to make sure the Razor pre-compiler interprets your Razor code as you want it to : mostly how to differentiate between Html attributes and component attributes/parameters? @HenkHolterman's answer below goes into the details.

Comment: i found a good explanation here https://blazor-university.com/components/literals-expressions-and-directives/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first distinction to be made here is between a Razor component tag and an HTML tag, as for instance to explain what is OnClick in the HxButton component, and how it is compared to @onclick in the button tag. So let me expand a little bit on this and other related difficulties, so that the baffled reader can get a better understanding of the subject.

HxButton is a Razor component that has a parameter attribute named OnClick already assigned with the value "StartClick", which is the name of a method defined in the parent component. This method may have parameters.

Parent container of `HxButton` component

```
<HxButton OnClick="StartClick"/>

@code
{
   private void StartClick (string value)
   {

   } 
}
```

How many parameters and their types is determined in the definition of the HxButton component. Here's the definition of the OnClick parameter property in the component:

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnClick {get; set;}
```

Note that this event 'delegate' encapsulates a method that has a single parameter of type string. When this delegate is executed from within the HxButton component , as for instance, `OnClick.InvokeAsync(value);`, the `StartClick` method assigned to the parameter attribute `OnClick` in the instantiation of `HxButton` is called and a string value is passed to it.

OnClick is defined as a property, and the compiler has no difficulties in seeing it. @onclick in the button Html tag is a compiler directive attribute. It instructs the compiler that the value assigned to the attribute should be a method that is called when the `click` event of the button element is triggered. It also tells the compiler to create behind the scenes, an event call back of the EventCallback 'delegate' to represent the call back method.

But you may use a construct like this: `onclick="alert('Hello')".` In that case, `onclick` is treated by the compiler as a pure Html attribute, and it is rendered `as is`. To distinguish between these two possibilities you'll have to instruct the compiler what you want to do. So is the usage of the at "sign". Incidentally, `onclick="alert('Hello')"`, is pure JavaScript.

Note: The value assigned to the `OnClick` parameter attribute is an expression that should evaluate to `EventCallback<string>`, thus it can be the name of a method, but also a lambda expression, as for instance:

`OnClick="@((value) => StartClick(value)"`

Note also that the name of the method can be prepended with the `@` sign like this: `OnClick="@StartClick"`

This was necessary when Blazor was in its initial development phase. It is no longer necessary, but the user is not enforced not to use it. It took me some time to get rid of the habit of using it like this. Nowadays, I always skip the `@` sign.

To wrap it up, all the compiler directive attributes should be prepended with the `@` sign, such as @ref @onclick @oninput, etc.

> Why does StartButtonText have an @ sign

Because it is an expression that should evaluate to a string value. First off, I'd advise you to use it with enclosing quotes, like this:

`<HxButton Text="@StartButtonText" />`

Note: `"@StartButtonText"` is a string interpolation expression that enable data binding between the `Text` property defined on the `HxButton` component, and the variable `StartButtonText` defined on the hosting component.

Note also that you must apply the `@` sign, otherwise, the string Text property will contain the string `StartButtonText` instead of the value stored in the variable `StartButtonText`

> Why is ThemeColor.Primary in quotes but not StartButtonText

This question belongs in the department of human nature, or perhaps it should be directed at [Peter Morris](https://blazor-university.com/components/literals-expressions-and-directives/) whose treatise leads to anarchy instead of observance of uniformity. I'm specifically referrring to him because you've provided a link to what you called `a good explanation`

Anyhow, you can do it either like this: `Color="ThemeColor.Primary"`
or like this: `Color="@ThemeColor.Primary"` or like this: `Color=ThemeColor.Primary` or like this: `Color=@ThemeColor.Primary`

If you ask the author of your code: `Why is ThemeColor.Primary in quotes but not StartButtonText`, he'll probably try to to blame human inconsistency rather than his incompetency.

The Visual Studio editor automatically insert the double quotations within which you should provide a value, and that is how it should be done. Personal preferences, as preached by Peter Morris can be bad to society. And your question was good one, as it shows the existence of such absurd inconsistency in the same line: Yes, why enclose `ThemeColor.Primary` in quotes but not StartButtonText....

Comment: i liked Morrises explanation , I didnt really take in his suggestions of what quoting to use etc. The author of the HxButton line is me, the Color bit comes from their docs, but they had hard coed text, I worked out that @XXX was needed and guessed at syntax

Comment: The two answers offer an historical explanation why the multiple Blazor component declaration options evolved so thankyou @enet and @H H for the detail. However going forward the simplified Peter Morris syntax conventions linked to earlier will be adopted in my code.

Answer (score 8):

Blazor is the meeting point for two languages, C# and HTML. Moreover, both languages allow multiple syntax variants in some cases.

> - Why do some tags have an @ at the start of the name (like ref and onclick) and others not.

The [directive attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#directive-attributes) (`@ref`, `@key`, `@onclick` etc) need an `@` in front to indicate that they are C#. This is necessary because these attributes often have HTML/JS equivalents. They start with a lower-case letter.

When a Component defines a Parameter then you don't need an `@` but it is allowed. The very first versions of Blazor required it.

Everything else is passed on to HTML/JS.

> - Why is ThemeColor.Primary in quotes but not StartButtonText

StartButtonText would have been better in quotes, but this is a leniency in HTML. `Text="@StartButtonText"` is recommended.

> - Why does StartButtonText have an @ sign

This is the main 'switch' of Blazor (Razor syntax). Without the `@` you would see the string "StartButtonText" on the screen. With the `@` it becomes the name of a C# variable. This is the same `@` as in `@foreach() {...}`.

When a delegate (method) is expected the `@` is allowed but not required.

> - Why does the @onclick for the button have plain text (not @Show or "Show")

At this point it is already clear that `Show` has to be a C# method. You would get an error if it wasn't. There is no need for an `@` to switch languages. But C# allows an `@` in front of any name. It is an escape rule that lets you use reserved words like `int @int = 3;` but it is also allowed for unreserved words. Using `Show` or `"Show"` is again a leniency of HTML.

`@onclick="Show"` is recommended.

Comment: Specifically on `Text=@StartButtonText` and string Parameters, `Text` will be declared in the component as [Parameter]public string Text {get; set;}.  If you do `Text="StartButtonText"`, you are passing it a string "StartButtonText": the Razor pre-compiler doesn't know the difference.  To tell the pre-compiler that you actually want to use a C# variable you use the `@` prefix.  Just about everything else doesn't matter: in `Count=myCounterProperty` where Count is an `int`, `myCounterProperty` can't be interpreted any other way, so the pre-compiler gets it right.

Comment: @enet it would help if you provided a complete answer, its easier to read then. Plus it can be marked as correct