# Why do some blazor component properties start with an "at" (@) symbol?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I do not understand why some component argument parameter names starts with `@` and others do not.

For example:

```
<MyCustomComponent MyCustomParameter="somevalue" />
```

and

```
<MyCustomComponent @ref="@MyComponent" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can somebody explain the various syntaxes for Blazor component tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616962/can-somebody-explain-the-various-syntaxes-for-blazor-component-tags)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to create a custom directive attribute ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are not using an `@` sign, it means you don't want the transcompiler to intervene. So this is almost as same a a pure HTML/JS code.

Since you are already using a custom component made in blazer, the transcompiler knows that it has to parse the custom parameters inside the component, so you are not required to have any `@` signs.

In the second example you are using a blazer specific feature, so you are using `@`, in other words, this is how it's designed. Always treat `@ref` as something special **directive**. In this case blazer transcompiler will intervene and put its code in the middle without you knowing.

For value assignments with and without `@`, when you are hard coding, or doing an html/JS reference you don't need to put `@`, if you are assigning a blazer value, you are required  to put `@`

> Note: Currently, unlike other frameworks such as Angular, Blazor does not allow developers to create their own directives.

Refer below.
https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/